# How to apply the PUT verb in a REST request?

Tags: http, rest

I'm working on a REST server. I have an order RESOURCE.

From my understanding the PUT verb should create a new order based on the URL. My question is: How can this work if the resource is new and you don't know the ID of the new order?

I know the debate about POST vs PUT, but I'm quoting the w3 specs for PUT http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

"If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI"

Comment: I think PUT is usually modify/replace while POST is add (and wouldn't require an ID).  But I'm sure others will be able to give more details.

Comment: If you don't know the ID (and therefore the URI), you cannot use PUT.

Comment: Also, this question is not germane to C# or php.  Please retag appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RESTful APIs, `PUT` is typically used to *update* a resource or *create* one if it doesn't exist at the specified URL (i.e. the client provides the id). If the server generates the id, RESTful APIs typically use a `POST` to create new resources. In the latter scenario, the generated id/url is usually returned or specified in a redirect.

Example: `POST /orders/`

Comment: If a POST creates a new resource, it should return a HTTP 201 Created response.

Comment: @seairth Right. Or an HTTP 202 when asynchronous or an appropriate error code when things go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) Both `PUT` and `POST` can be used for update and/or create.
The basic difference between them is how the server handles the *Request-URI*. `PUT` URI identifies the entity and the server should't try to map it to another URL, while `POST` URI can be a handler for that content. Examples:

It's OK to `POST` a new order to `/order`, but not a `PUT`. You can update order 1 with a `PUT` or `POST` to `/order/1`.

Comment: Good answer for the original question.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply `POST` is for creating and `PUT` is for updating. If you don't have an ID for an object because it isn't created yet, you should be using a `POST`. If an object DOES exist and you just don't have the ID for it, you're going to have to search for it using a `GET` of some kind.

The thing to remember is [Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). A `PUT` (and `GET` for that matter) is idempotent. Basically meaning, you can hit the same URL over and over and it shouldn't make a difference the 2nd or 3rd time (It edits the data once, and calling it again it doesn't make that change again). However a `POST` is *not* idempotent. Meaning, you hit the same URL 3 or 4 times in a row and it's going to keep changing data (creating more and more objects). This is why a browser will warn you if you click back to a `POST` url.

Answer (score 0):

You say, "don't know the ID of the new order" therefore the following is not true "URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent", therefore PUT is not appropriate in your scenario.

Where is the confusion?  I am of course assuming the Id would be part of the URL.